# How to distribute an Iphone app internally

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

My company has built a flutter app that we don't want to release to the public.

How would we distribute the app to private clients with Iphones.

Can someone please give me some insight on how to go about doing this as I can't find a clear answer on the internet.

I've seen services like https://appho.st/ but how does this work? Does the app still need to be signed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not about code.

Comment: If you have 100 or more employees, start here [Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/). Otherwise, start here [Distribute](https://developer.apple.com/distribute/). This, in particular, may help [Custom Apps](https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/)

Comment: If your client list is very small you can ask them for their UUIDs and then roll out builds with those devices included if the options suggested by Don does not suit you

Comment: You probably have two choices. The first is a custom app. The app is uploaded to AppStore connect as normal and reviewed but you set it for custom distribution to a single organisation via Apple Business Manager. The second is your company enrols in the enterprise developer program which lets you distribute apps directly to employees. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667 And https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304 are worth watching